# How to check multiple database using AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer?

Tags: c#, health-check

Currently I have checked for one database using these code:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
               .AddSqlServer(
                 connectionString: Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                 healthQuery: "SELECT 1;",
                 name: "sql",
                 failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
                 tags: new string[] { "db", "sql", "sqlserver" }
               );
```

But how do I check multiple database? I am using .NET Core 3.1 and AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer Version=3.1.1.

Comment: just curious, can you add multiple .AddSqlServer within AddHealthChecks ?
otherwise you might think of apply mutliple AddCheck Method

Comment: When I add another .AddSql, it says `Duplicate health checks were registered with the name(s): sql (Parameter 'registrations')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add another `AddSqlServer` method but with different `name`. `name` must be unique.

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSqlServer(
        connectionString: Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        healthQuery: "SELECT 1;",
        name: "sql",
        failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
        tags: new string[] { "db", "sql", "sqlserver" })
    .AddSqlServer(
        connectionString: Configuration.GetConnectionString("AnotherConnection"),
        healthQuery: "SELECT 1;",
        name: "sql2",
        failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
        tags: new string[] { "db", "sql", "sqlserver" }
           );
```